# htaccess rewriterule to redirect to new domain

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need to redirect **all articles** from an old domain to a new domain. Old domain articles (non wordpress site) slugs are like:

```
www.olddomain.com/CATEGORY_NAME/ID_ARTICLE/ARTICLE_SLUG
```

New domain articles (wordpress site) slugs are like:

```
www.newdomain.com/ARTICLE_SLUG
```

So, I need htaccess rules to redirect from old domain to the new one, that is, removing the two first segments of the old domain (CATEGORY_NAME and ID_ARTICLE).

At the moment, I have this in the htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www. newdomain .com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But it makes redirection with all urls.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```bsh
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.olddomain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$3 [L,R=301,QSA]
```

Lose the `[L]` flag, if there are further rewrites ahead in the file.

I [tested it online](http://htaccess.mwl.be/) and it seems to be working as you want:

[image: Redirect old domain with new domain dropping the first two segments]